# How to count odd digits in unsigned long number in C

Tags: c

My professor's rules for this are:

Write a recursive function with the signature:

```
int check_odd(unsigned long n);
```

The function gets a natural positive number `n`. The function needs to check if the number of the different odd digits that appear in `n` is less than 3. If they are: return 1 else return 0.
You can't use any other functions and also can't use static/global variables.

Examples:

```
check_odd(2169876)==0 
check_odd(956908529)==1
```

This is the code I did so far and it works up to a point:

```
 int check_odd(unsigned long n) {      
    if (n / 10 == 0) {
        return n % 2 != 0 ? 1 : 0;
    }
    else {
        return (n % 10 % 2 != 0? 1:0)+check_odd(n/10);
    }
}
```

This recursive function returns me how many odd digits there are in the number. Now I don't know how to continue and check if the digits are the same or different digits and I need to return 0 if there are 3 or more different odd digits; else 1.

Comment: How would you check whether the least significant digit is odd or even?  How would you get rid of that digit so you could test the second least significant digit in the original number?  When would you stop?  That's how you'd do it.  (What should you do with exactly 3 odd digits?  If the number is 1010101, does that count as 4 'odd different digits' or is it the same odd digit 4 times over?)

Comment: Believe me, I tried lots of hours. maybe you can show me how i need to write this program?

Comment: @DanielBeckBachar - then post the code that you have written so far...

Comment: @DanielBeckBacharthen show us what code you produced and explain where it failed,etc.

Comment: so i tried a few things, this code only counts how many odd numbers i have: int check_odd(unsigned long n) {
    
    if (n / 10 == 0) {
        return n % 2 != 0 ? 1 : 0;
    }
    else {
        return (n % 10 % 2 != 0? 1:0)+check_odd(n/10);
    }
}

Comment: and it is working but now i cant understand how i can check if there is more 3 different odd digits to return 0 or else to return 1

Comment: Edit the question to include your best effort at coding the result.  The return value of 0 or 1 is going to be a nuisance.  It would be much simpler if the recursive function simply returned the count of the number of odd digits and let the calling code decide what to do with more, less or exactly 3 odd digits.  In context, I'd probably have a private recursive function to do the counting (assuming I used recursion at all, which I wouldn't), and then a wrapper function which calls the recursive function and compares what it returns with 3 and returns what is needed.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler  but in the question i cant use any static objects, or another functions to help me..

Comment: How were we to know that there were extra rules imposed on you?  We can't divine what your sadistic teacher has set as rules — you have to tell us so we don't go off track.  Add that information to the question too, please.  And please read the [About] and [Ask] pages (and about how to create an MCVE — [MCVE]).  It is hard work (much too much hard work) getting the information needed out of you.  You need to tell us the rules so we don't have to find them out the hard way.  The "cannot use any other function" rule is going to hurt.

Comment: @DanielBeckBachar Are you sure that `check_odd` has to be a recursive function itself? My guess is that `check_odd` is allowed to do its job by using **another** recursive function. Like `return (count_odd(n) < 3)` where `count_odd` is recursive.

Answer (score 2):

@Daniel Beck Bachar: You're idea to treat digits 3 by 3 was genial. It inspires me for a solution.
Also note that (n&1) is the same as n%2.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int check_odd(unsigned long n)
{
    int d1, d2, d3, n2;

    if (n < 100)
        return 1;

    d1 = n%10; // digit for units
    d2 = (n/10)%10; // digit for tens
    d3 = (n/100)%10; // digit for hundreds

    // We try to remove some of the three digits
    // A digit can be removed if it is even
    // Or if it is the same as another of the 2 other digit
    n2 = n / 1000;
    if ((d3&1) == 1)
        n2 = n2*10 + d3;
    if ((d2&1) == 1 && d2 != d3)
        n2 = n2*10 + d2;
    if ((d1&1) == 1 && d1 != d2 && d1 != d3)
        n2 = n2*10 + d1;
    if (n == n2) // If all 3 digits are kept, that means they are all odd and differents
        return 0;

    return check_odd(n2); // Since n2 < n, one day or the other the recursion will end.
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    unsigned int n;

    n = atoi(argv[1]);
    printf("check_odd(%d) = %d\n", n, check_odd(n));
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: because of operator precedence I put parenthesis around `(n&1)`, since `==` evaluates first. Thx to chqrlie.

Comment: Your solution is excellent!, just one small problem: `d2&1 == 1` is parsed as `d2 & (1 == 1)`. It works by chance because `1 == 1` evaluates to `1`.

Answer (score 0):

```
int check_odd(unsigned int n) {
  unsigned int m = 0;
  for ( ; n ; n /= 10)
    m |= (n & 1) << ((n % 10) / 2);
  m = m - ((m >> 1) & 0x55555555);
  m = (m & 0x33333333) + ((m >> 2) & 0x33333333);
  return (((m + (m >> 4) & 0xF0F0F0F) * 0x1010101) >> 24) < 3;
}
```

Comment: thank you for helping! but i need this function to be recursive function

Answer (score 0):

OK I finally solve this question!

```
int check_odd(unsigned long n) {
    if ((n / 1000) == 0) {
        if (((n%10) != ((n%100)/10)) &&
            (n%10) != ((n%1000)/100) &&
            ((n%100)/10) != ((n%1000)/100) &&
            (n%10)%2 != 0 && ((n%100)/10)%2 != 0 && ((n%1000)/100)%2 != 0) {
            return 0;
        } else
            return 1;
    } else {
        if ((n%10)%2 == 0) {
            return check_odd(n/10);
        } else {
            int i = 100;
            while ((n%10)%2) {
                if (((n%i)/(i/10))%2 == 0) {
                    unsigned long temp = n/i;
                    n = (temp*(i/10)) + (n%(i/10));
                    return check_odd(n);
                } else
                if (((n%10)) == ((n%i)/(i/10))){
                    return check_odd(n/10);
                }
                i = i * 10;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No - just try `printf("%d\n", check_odd(2169876));` - It doesn't result in 0 with your code

Comment: for me its return 0 for - 2169876

Comment: Nope - `printf("%d\n", check_odd(2169876));` result in 1 with your code.

Comment: check_odd(123456789) results in an infinite loop :( But I think you're not far from the answer :)